# Android Studio AVD's Not launching HELP

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing a school project using Android Studio and I can't seem to get my AVD to launch. I'm using the school's 32bit Linux computers.

I'm running into this error when I try to launch an AVD.

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

I have tried going into the run configurations and adding the -force-32bit- command to the Additional command line options, and I've tried opening a gedit. profile and adding the **export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true** to it, but it still gives me the same error above.

I can't switch to a 64bit computer, and I am fairly new to the program so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't reloaded your profile. The change will only take effect after that (e.g., reboot, restart terminal).

Try setting the env var for the command only. Go to the terminal and type:
`ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true avd`
(Or whatever the command is called.)