# Error when running Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio

Firstly, I want you all to know that I am completely new to Android development and this is the first time I'm trying to run an Android virtual device.

I get the following when I run an Android virtual device form Android Studio:

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
   you will have to do at least one of the following:
   - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
   - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
   Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
   aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
   Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

How will I do any of that (e.g. use `'-force-32bit'`)?

I use Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit, which **is** running independently on my laptop and **not** running on a virtual box. I have enabled Virtualization Technology.

Comment: I came across [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629961/android-studio-avds-not-launching-help) but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

To start an instance of the emulator from the command line, navigate to the `tools/` folder of the SDK. Enter emulator command like this:

> `emulator -avd <avd_name> [<options>]`

you can add your avd name in place of `<avd_name>` and the `-force-32bit` in place of `[<options>]`

Read docs [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) to understand more about controlling emulators from command-line.

To do this from Android studio, you can edit or Create a Run Configuration:

1. Open **Edit Configurations** from the **Run** Menu.
2. Expand the **Android Application** item and create a new configuration or open an existing one.
3. With the Run Configuration selected, adjust your desired run configuration settings:

   In the **Emulator** tab, specify any emulator options to the **Additional Emulator Command Line Options** field. So put `-force-32bit` here.

Read more about this in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html).

Comment: Any way to do it graphically, i.e. from Android Studio?

Comment: Still getting the error... Would I have to restart Android Studio, or maybe my computer?