# Unable to launch AVD manager

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I am unable to launch AVD manager in ubuntu 14.04 as while installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM) It says not compatible with linux what shoud i do in such a case I am new to Android and Ubuntu both.
The error is as follows

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Comment: Look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642660/error-when-running-android-virtual-device/642668#642668